# Asp.net validator type in javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, validation

Is it possible to get the type of asp.net validator in javascript.
here what i tried so far but not working.

```
document.getElementByID("validator_id").type
```

but this always generate javascript error.
any suggestions to get type of validator.

Comment: asp validator's gets converted to javascript code at run time.. So why do you need the type of validator..? More information might be of help..

Comment: for each type of validator i have different type of classes in css in case of validation failure that i want to use. thats why i need the type of validator.

Comment: there is a facility of CssClass in asp validators..

Comment: is it possible to get cssclass in javascript of validator

Comment: validators would be fired when the page would be submitted... and the complete process will be done using javascript... Still my question remains the same **more information to help us to help you**..

Comment: what all i am doing is that i have validator in my webform and on page sumbit there is a javascript function that itreate on page validators and check the isvalid property. if isvalid is false i need to add the appropriate css class to that control that is associate to the validator. and foreach validor type i have different class in css.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your brief question **"what all i am doing is that i have validator in my webform and on page sumbit there is a javascript function that itreate on page validators and check the isvalid property. if isvalid is false i need to add the appropriate css class to that control that is associate to the validator. and foreach validor type i have different class in css"**

One line solution is ***"there is a facility of CssClass in asp validators.."***

**If you want to know the type of validator** add an attribute named `data-type` in the validator and provide the value of it..
For Ex. `<asp:RequiredFieldValidator data-type="required" ID="v1" runat="server" ErrorMessage="RequiredFieldValidator" ControlToValidate="TextBox1"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>`
You can get it using `document.getElementById("v1").getAttribute('data-type')`

**Other Alternate**
If you want to add something more than usual in your webform with each `input` add a (hidden)paragraph and then on page submit fire a javascript that checks individual `input` for validation.. If valid then its fine.. If not then show the paragraph..

Comment: If you are planning to use the **"Other Alternate"** [this jQuery plugin](http://jquery.bassistance.de/validate/demo/) might help..

Answer (score 0):

```
var x=document.getElementById("validator_id");
alert(x.innerHTML);
```

.value instead of .type. So you can get value or validator_id

Comment: No i don't neet the validator id or value. i need the type of this validator. e.g required or range or regularexpressionvalidator etc.